Where did this site's 'icon' originate from?
Just curious... where did this site's 'icon' come from.
I should know this, but is it universal, or unique to this site? Is it perhaps a logo of something?
On the "happy birthday to us" post, it is also on a cake that appears in an X (formerly Twitter) post.

I boldly hijacked the cake photo because because it fitted soo nicely. It's not the same logo though.
